# How can I use useParams( ) method in dispatch method to store my data in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a blog site with Django REST at the backend. I am trying to fetch individual post details using dispatch method to store data in redux. But I can not figure out how to use useParams( ) in here. Can anyone help me out, please?

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../resources/scss/blogpost.scss'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { listPost } from '../actions/postActions'

function BlogPage({match}) {
    const postDetails = useSelector(state => state.postDetails)
    
    const { error, loading, post } = postDetails
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listPost(useParams(id)))
    }, [id])

  return (
    <div>
        <div className='post_container'>
          <img className='post_image' src= {post.image} alt='{post.category}' /> &nbsp;
          <h3>{post.title}</h3> &nbsp;
          <p>{post.author}</p>
          <p className='post_excerpt'> " {post.excerpt} "</p> &nbsp;
          <div className='post_body' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:post.content}}></div>
          
          
          <h1 className='comment_head'>Comments</h1>
        </div> 
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default BlogPage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// First get out your query from use query like this
const { param } = useParams();
const dispatch = useDispatch();
// Then call your useEffect with your params in dependency array

  useEffect(() => {
const callDispatch = async () => {
  dispatch(yourFunction(param));
  try {
    dispatch(yourFunction(param));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
if (param) {
  getDetails();
} 
}, 
[param,dispatch]);
```